# ¿Cómo activo la persistencia de datos Firebase en Android correctamente?

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Tengo un error al activar la persistencia de *Firebase* en Android, me ocurre un error con la aplicación.

La aplicación al ser abierta por primera vez logra obtener los datos de forma más rápida (lo cual denota que esta accediendo a la cache), pero al presionar el botón back, salir de la aplicación y volver a entrar  esta se cierra a brutalmente.

Solo he puesto esta línea de código:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

¿Se debe realizar alguna otra modificación para que no ocurra esta salida abrupta? Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: Hecho, si hay algún fallo seria tan amable de decirme en que parte?

Comment: @JoseA.HuancaAncajima en Android es indispensable el uso del LogCat, que mensaje se muestra , agregalo a tu pregunta. Decir se cierra puede deberse a otra razón, no precisamente a la linea que comentas.

Comment: Si, pero por mi computadora contar con poco ram y ser un poco antigua no uso ningún emulador sino directo en mi celular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para activarla crea una clase que extienda de `Application`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` define en la propiedad `android:name` esta clase:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment: me funciono muchas gracias :)

Comment: Excelente @JoseA.HuancaAncajima un saludo.